# why this code can't work under IE?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
   $html .= '<div id="submit">  
 <input type="image" name="subscribe" onmouseover="this.src=\'images/1_hv.jpg\'" onmouseout="this.src=\'images/1.jpg\'"
src="images/1.jpg"
 value="'.$data["button"].'" onClick="return checkform();"></div>
<a id="cancel" href="'.getConfig("unsubscribeurl").'&id='.$id.'">'.$GLOBALS["strUnsubscribe"].'</a>
</form>
'.$GLOBALS["PoweredBy"];
```

why  this input code can't work under IE? when i click the image under IE, it can't work. it can't submit the form. namely,it can't subscribe the newsletter.but ok under chrome and Firefox.

when i change it into

```
     <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="'.$data["button"].'" onClick="return     checkform();">
```

when under IE,firefox,chrome. all can work .

Comment: Which part doesn't work?

Comment: Backslashes in the strings doing pointless escaping?  No spaces between attributes after the `onmouseout` handler?  Have you tried running it through the w3c validator?

Comment: @jeffamaphone - not pointless this code is part of an echo I suppose check the `$data["button"]` please paste more code also the JS part..

Comment: @pst - why? if he is using `echo 'blabla.. value="'.$var.' blabla';` ??

Comment: when i click the image button,it can't submit the form. namely,it can't subscribe the newsletter. but under firefox and chrome. it can. so i think the $data["button"] is ok. when i change it into

Comment: <input type="submit" name="subscribe" value="'.$data["button"].'" onClick="return checkform();"> this,when under IE,firefox,chrome. all can work.

Comment: why using slashes in the image name? `image/1.jpg` ??

Comment: $html .= '<div id="submit">   has this '

Comment: Looking at serverside code never solves looking at clientside problems. View the page source and see what is being outputted.

Comment: @runeveryday - are you answering my question? if the image doesn't include the slash `/` then remove it!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you're abusing `<input type="image">` to have a button with a background image. The `<input type="image">` is intented as an image map where you'd be interested in the X and Y coordinates of the mouse pointer on the button. Those values are namely sent as request parameters.

In HTML/PHP terms, the

```
<input type="image" name="subscribe">
```

will be available as

```
$x = $_POST['subscribe.x']; // Contains X coordinate of mouse pointer on button.
$y = $_POST['subscribe.y']; // Contains Y coordinate of mouse pointer on button.
```

However, on modern browsers other than MSIE, also the "plain" name and value of the button is been sent along, probably with the intention to be more forgiving on poorly designed websites.

```
$subscribe = $_POST['subscribe']; // Contains "value" of button.
```

Relying on `$_POST['subscribe']` in the server side explains why your form doesn't work on MSIE.

See also this extract of the w3 HTML spec:

> ### [17.4.1 Control types created with INPUT](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1)
>
> ...
>
> **image**
>
> Creates a graphical submit button. The value of the `src` attribute specifies the URI of the image that will decorate the button. For accessibility reasons, authors should provide alternate text for the image via the `alt` attribute.
>
> When a pointing device is used to click on the image, the form is submitted and the click coordinates passed to the server. The x value is measured in pixels from the left of the image, and the y value in pixels from the top of the image. **The submitted data includes *name.x=x-value* and *name.y=y-value* where "name" is the value of the `name` attribute, and *x-value* and *y-value* are the x and y coordinate values, respectively.**

---

So, to fix your problem, you have 2 options:

1. Check for presence of `subscribe.x` and/or `subscribe.y` request parameter instead to take action accordingly (not recommended).
2. Don't abuse image input type with the sole purpose to have a background on the button, just use CSS (more recommended):

   ```
   <input type="submit" id="subscribe" name="subscribe">
   ```

   with

   ```
   #subscribe {
       border: 0;
       width: 100px; /* Let it match the actual image's dimensions. */
       height: 20px; /* Let it match the actual image's dimensions. */
       background-image: url('images/1.jpg');
   }
   #subscribe:hover {
       background-image: url('images/1_hv.jpg');
   }
   ```

   Note that `:hover` pseudoselector doesn't work in IE6 on elements other than `<a>`, but I don't expect that you would care about this browser. If you do, then have a look in the JS corner for the solution.